# Integrating IP core to a project

Tags: fpga, lattice

I'm working on a Lattice board and I'm want to to use IP cores for my project. I have a license to a third party IP core but I have no idea how to integrate the IP  to my project. My research shows me that the info available online is specific to different design tools and I haven't found one for Lattice Diamond. My question is, are different IP cores implemented differently or is there a general method to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask the vendor of the IP.

To answer your question, IP cores can be implemented differently

1. An encrypted netlist. This is specific to the vendor, and more often that not the specific series of parts.
2. A VHDL/Verilog file. This is typically more expensive. This is more common for ASICs.

Comment: In #1, are you talking about the IP vendor or the target chip vendor? You might want to make that clear.